# Google Analitys : utmp var encoded show undecoded characters in GA

Tags: java, mobile, google-analytics

I'm using the var encoded using java to send a PageView to GA this way :

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif? ... &utmp=%2FEntrar%20en%20App& ...
```

The problem is that GA isn't decoding de `%2F` (forward slash) and `%20` (space) in the online view like this:

Active Page

> %2FEntrar%20en%20App

Any idea of how must i do this to avoid that problem ? , maybe any other param involve?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the answer , If you use old google analytics version , it doesn't do it well.

Use this (up) version instead :

> utmwv=4.8.1ma